# How to specify a foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created 3 tables in a music tracks database 
Track ( id, album, genre)
Album( id, title)
Contributed ( artist, track, role)

I have chosen Id as primary keys for the first table, ( I'd, album) for the second table.

Do I need a  primary key in my third table? What is my foreign key? How do I specify my foreign key?What are the unique identifiers in my third table? 
I tried to populate it using tracks as foreign key( referenced to Track table, id column) but it gives me error. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Your Database design is good (i miss the track-number in the table `Track`). Also the foreign key you try to create is correct. What exactly is the message of the error?

Answer (score 1):

For the third table, we can have two foreign keys:

- Referencing to artist table (assuming we have an artist table with id and name).
- Referencing to track table.

Syntax for foreign key should look like this (in create table script):

```
CONSTRAINT fk_contributed_track FOREIGN KEY
REFERENCS track(id)
```

[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) is an example of a create table script with foreign key.

As far as primary key is concerned, it depends on business rules (i.e. whether one artist can have multiple roles for a track). However, for simple design, I would recommend having a numeric `auto increment` primary key.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can accept my answer, as it helped you.